# Getting error while opening file , i have created folder with book_name > chapter_name in code and then creating file

Tags: ruby, string, file

> In child folder(chapter_number), i am creating file

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require 'roo'

Dir.glob("**/*.xlsx") do |file|
  xlsx = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file)
  bookname = xlsx.column(1)

  cahpter_number_array = xlsx.column(2).uniq

  cahpter_number_array.each do |chapter|
   book_name      = bookname[1] if bookname
   chapter_number = chapter if (cahpter_number_array && (chapter != "Chapter"))

   Dir.mkdir(book_name) unless File.exists?(book_name)
   Dir.mkdir("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}") unless File.exists?("#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}")

   xlsx.column(3).each do |md|
    output_name = "#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}/#{File.basename(md.partition('-').first, '.*')}.md" if (md != "Verse")
    output = File.open("#{output_name}", 'w')
    output << "hello"
   end
 end
end
```

## Error:

> `initialize': Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - . (Errno::EISDIR)

## Below link is my source file:

[source file link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_-sckPdT2dlak9fbFZYVC1SVGs/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: Your example doesn't raise that exception

Comment: Now you can check, i have changed above code as original previous was pseudo code

Comment: please now vote as up :(

Comment: Please don't beg for upvotes.

Comment: ok! same code showing error to other guy and you did not why?

Comment: @Codebeef Can you share me where you are not seeing error.

Answer (score 1):

Come on now, that isn't really your code. You can't call partition on a number:

```
file_name = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]

file_name.each do |md|
  ... md.partition('-')
```

so you would have gotten an error for that before getting the error you posted.

In any case, the error message is saying that `outputname` is set equal to `"."` and when ruby tries to execute `File.open(".", 'w')` ruby finds that `"."` is the name of a directory on your system, and you can't write a directory.  You can witness the same error doing this:

```
~/ruby_programs$ mkdir my_dir
~/ruby_programs$ irb
2.3.0 :001 > File.open('my_dir', 'w')
Errno::EISDIR: Is a directory @ rb_sysopen - my_dir
    from (irb):1:in `initialize'
    from (irb):1:in `open'
    from (irb):1
    from /Users/7stud/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/irb:11:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Sorry for that: i have changed my code instead of "md.partition('-')" please use "md" only.
above code was like ["1-3", "4-7"....] thats why i was partining.

Comment: I have changed my all code now. Earlier that was pseudo code.

Comment: I agree with your solution but if you check my line i am creating file, dir is already created:
output_name = "#{book_name}/#{chapter_number}/#{File.basename(md, '.*')}.md" if (md != "Verse")
 output = File.open("#{output_name}", 'w')
 output << "hello"

Comment: @umishra, What do you see if you add  `puts "--->#{output_name}<---"` after the line `output_name = ....`?   If you still get the same error, then you should see the output `--->.<---` right before the error.

Comment: @umishra, `above code was like ["1-3", "4-7"....] thats why i was partining`--Then why are you calling `File.basename("1", ".*")`?  That's just `"1"`.

Comment: If you are not checking my code then you do not have right pointing error. I have changed my above all code before 17 hrs and you are showing me error as per previos pseudo code. Please check my all code again and still you have query let me know.

Comment: @umishra, The error quoted in your post hasn't changed from the first time you posted.  As I have no intention ever to run your code, I think it's time for me to take my leave.  Good luck.

Comment: Ah previous was with pseudo code, now that is working code. You can check my file which i shared in above line as name "source file link" thanks